# 4 Monitors and a Projector with Radeon 6700/6800 series

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, projector

I have two graphics cards, one is a [Radeon HD 6700 series](http://www.gigabyte.com.au/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3864&dl=1#utility) and one is a [Radeon HD 6850](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3630#sp).

Both have dual DVI ports, a display port and a HDMI port. So all up, I have 8 ports that I assumed I should be able to hook 8 monitors up to... that doesn't appear to be the case :(

I have four monitors connected up to the DVI slots, and one HDMI projector plugged in. Apparently I can't connect the projector without disabling one of my monitors which is a pain. Does anyone know of any way for me to get the projector working without having to disable a monitor? Either that or why do they ship with 4 ports when you can only use 2 at a time M_M :@ fuu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the cards can drive only 3 displays, but only it can only drive two HDMI/DVI monitors.  You can use only 2 out of the 3 HDMI and DVI ports.  The third monitor has to be a Display Port.  To connect an HDMI adapter to the DisplayPort you'll need an active DisplayPort to HDMI adapter.

See more details at [ATI's site](http://support.amd.com/us/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-dongles.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got out a DP to HDMI adapter and it still doesn't work :\? I have 2x DVI plugged in and 1x DP (via HDMI:DP adapter). Is there something else that might be restricting it? Does that mean I have a 'passive' dongle instead of an 'active' one??? It doesn't say anywhere on the box what it is :\

Comment: It's probably passive. Does it take external power (possibly through a USB port)?  If not it's definitely passive.

Comment: Nah there's no other power source. Well that sucks, thanks for your help then!

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Eyefinity

Answer (score 0):

MST hub - DisplayPort to 3x DisplayPort will allow to connect 3 more im having a similar issue and this is the fix per amd.